# mvc core2.0 routing is not Workin

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Here i'm new to mvc core2.0 please help me why my Routing Is not working
My Routing Class

```
public static class ApplicationRoteProfiler
    {
        public static void Routeing(IRouteBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.MapRoute("route1", "", new
            {
                Controllers = "Department",
                Action = "Add",

            });
            builder.MapRoute("route2", "Department/Add", new
            {
                Controllers = "Department",
                Action = "Index"

            });
        }
```

This class file i register in startup.config file

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                ApplicationRoteProfiler.Routeing(routes);
            });

        }
```

When i hit my server as `http://localhost:1588/Department/Add` its should redirect to Department/Index But its hitting Department/Add

Answer (score 1):

Should it be just `Controller` not `Controllers`??

```
builder.MapRoute("route1", "", new { controller = "department", action = "index" });
```

### My 2 cents

1. You shouldn't use `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` and `app.UseMvc()` at the same time. You only need to pick 1 of them.
2. I don't see benefits of using a static class to configure routing for MVC. You can just put all the route configurations right there inside `UseMvc` lamba function. Also I don't think you need to put customized route specifically for your "route1" as it follows the standard MVC routing convention.

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       // The order of these routes matters!

       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "route2",
           template: "department/add",
           defaults: new { area = "", controller = "department", action = "index" });

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "default",
          template: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
   }
   ```
3. You can also `return RedirectToAction("index");` inside your `Department` controller `Add` method so whenever `/deparment/add` route is hit, it redirects to `/deparment/index`, assuming you have the default MVC routing setup, either use the "default" route I put on #2, or use `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`. That way you don't need to create custom routes just for redirecting.

   ```
   public class DepartmentController : Controller
   {
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }

       public IActionResult Add()
       {
           return RedirectToAction("index");
       }
   }
   ```